# Sharepoint Online - Add a user in a group - From where you add the users?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, groups, azure

I am adding some users in a default Sharepoint online group (Visitors of Sharepoint Site).

I am doing this from the interface Groups > Visitors of tenant Site > New > Share tenant Site window (watch the picture for precise info):

Add People in a Sharepoint group interface:

[image: Add People in a Sharepoint group interface]

Everything works except for one user that I can't find, we will call him Franko. I have tried to look with first name, last name, email... Nothing.

My question is, from where SharePoint is looking for users? Azure Active Directory "Users" group? Because this Franko is in AAD Users Group.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Is Franko a new user? does the user have the correct licenses?

Comment: Is user is available under active user in Microsoft Admin center?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out.

If I go on Azure > Azure Active Directory > Users, and I look for Franko, I see that the "Account enabled" column is set to "No". See picture below.

[image]

I ask the admin to change this value, they told me that Franko is in pension from 10 years. I guess we don't need this user so much.

Thanks to everyone for the help!